# onCharacteristicChanged is not called after writing on ble

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need some response data from Ble. When I am writing something on ble I need to read response data from Ble. I am able to successfully enable and disable my ble device but only missing response data from ble. I also need to convert decimal time into Integer hex format like for 60 min into 0x3c.

```
private BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback= new BluetoothGattCallback() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt,status);
            clientGatt =gatt;
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getServices().get(2);
                List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {

                    if (gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(AppConstant.RECEIVE_UUID)) {
                        readCharacteristic=gattCharacteristic;
                    }
                    if (gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(AppConstant.SEND_UUID_STR)) {
                        writeCharacteristic = gattCharacteristic;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt,characteristic,status);
            LogUtils.errorLog("onCharacteristicRead", "@@: "+characteristic.getValue()[0]);

        }
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic)

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);

            setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic,true);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

            clientGatt = gatt;

            switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    isBLE_Connected=true;
                    gatt.discoverServices();

                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    isBLE_Connected=false;
                    if(status==133 || status==22 || status==62){
                        refreshDeviceCache();
                        clientGatt.discoverServices();
                    }else{
                        clientGatt.disconnect();
                        clientGatt.close();
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le

Answer (score 5):

Before `onCharacteristicChanged` is called you had to enable notification.
Someting like:

```
   //Enable local notifications
    gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
    //Enabled remote notifications
    BluetoothGattDescriptor desc =characteristic.getDescriptor(CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR);
    desc.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    gatt.writeDescriptor(desc);
```

should help.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help.
Its working now. I was making mistake on characteristic descriptor selection.Now I have fixed it now.
Will you please answer my second question if you have any idea.

Comment: @Mike what does it mean by local notification and remote notification ?

Answer (score -1):

You when you write something on characteristic with the help of  **BluetoothGattDescriptor** as

> Mike's answer

You need to override the following method to listen to the changes has been completed then you can read the characteristics:

```
 @Override
public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
    super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
    Log.d(TAG, "onDescriptorWrite :" + ((status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) ? "Sucess" : "false"));
}
```

Comment: I got success onDescriptorWrite but I'm not getting onCharacteristicsRead() Callback any other solution?